# SQL - Calculate percentage of multiple counts

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I wrote a query to count and group all items in db by it's status.

Now, I need to calculate percentage of every given result.

```
    SELECT 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  as 'Pennding Requests',
      COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Accepted Requests',
      COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Denied' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Denied Requests'
    FROM meeting_request;
```

which gave me:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ8D3.png)

I tried something like:

```
       100.0 * (id / Pennding Requests) AS PERCENTAGE
```

Can some one suggest how to calculate percentage all of three status.

Comment: Percentage of what? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG( status = 'Pending' )  as pending_requests,
       AVG( status = 'Accepted' ) as Accepted_Requests,
       AVG( status = 'Denied' ) as Denied_Requests
FROM meeting_request;
```

Because MySQL interprets booleans as numbers with 1 for true and 0 for false, you can use the handy shortcut.  The more formal SQL code is:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this?

```
    SELECT 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / SUM(1) * 100.0  as 'Pennding Requests Percent',
      COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Accepted' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / SUM(1) * 100.0 as 'Accepted Requests Percent',
      COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Denied' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / SUM(1) * 100.0 as 'Denied Requests Percent'
    FROM meeting_request;
```